# WSO2 Data Services Server 3.2.2 jdbc error

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, wso2-data-services-server

I have a DSS 3.2.2 (latest patches) installed along with other WSO2 products on my test server, Win 7 64bit Enterprise with jdk 1.6.45 set up in JAVA_HOME. When I deploy a data-service definition (.dbs) that uses SQL Server 2008 R2 database, I get an exception. Tried switching to jdk 1.7, same outcome. Has anyone encountered this? Appreciate your help!

Data-service is configured with com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

dqljdbc4.jar is deployed to repository/components/lib

Stacktrace:

DS Fault Message: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
DS Code: CONNECTION_UNAVAILABLE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: XXXXXXX
Location: \XXXXXXX.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Nested Exception:-
java.sql.SQLException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.

```
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.RDBMSConfig.<init>(RDBMSConfig.java:42)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.getRDBMSConfig(ConfigFactory.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.createConfig(ConfigFactory.java:51)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceFactory.createDataService(DataServiceFactory.java:136)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.createDBService(DBDeployer.java:737)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.processService(DBDeployer.java:1083)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.deploy(DBDeployer.java:161)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
```

Comment: can you check what's inside repository/components/dropins (this is where the server copies libs after converting them to osgi bundles)

Comment: Thank you @rajeev-sampath, there were a few jdbc drivers there which I deleted and restarted the server. Everything deployed after that, no issues.